# How to enable buttons at start of gui in Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, button, netbeans

This is not a duplicate as I already know the code `.setEnabled(false);`. My problem is that I am making a gui in netbeans and I cannot figure out how to disable/enable buttons. Obviously I am new to JAVA and Netbeans This is what I have to do:

- Start the program with all buttons disabled except the Initialize
  button.
- When Initialize is pressed the ArrayList will be filled with 5 CD
  titles. The Initialize button then becomes disabled and the other
  buttons become enabled.
  The only code I know for buttons is `.setEnabled(false);` but it only disables button after I click it and what i need is to make one enabled and rest disabled. After I click it, it should be disabled and rest should be enabled.
  The current code is not relevant but if you need it I will edit this post! Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: In NetBeans you can set the JButton's enabled property to false in the form designer. Why not do this?

Comment: I am new to Netbeans and I have no idea how to do that

Comment: And that just disables it cant enable it again after the other buttons have been pressed

Answer (score -1):

You need to use interface ActionListener and add ActionListener  after clicking
of button. Implement default method ActionPerformed. Use this code as example.

```
                            import java.awt.*;
                               import java.awt.event.*;
               class calc extends Frame implements ActionListener 
                     {
                   TextField t1 =new TextField(20);
                   TextField t2 =new TextField(29);
                  TextField t3 =new TextField(29);
                    Label l1=new Label("first");
                     Label l2=new Label("second");
                     Label l3=new Label("sum");
                      Button b1=new Button("Add");
                     Button b2=new Button("close"); 
                    calc()     //CONSTRUCTOR
                     {
                            add(l1);add(t1);
                               add(t2);add(l2);
                                 add(t3);add(l3);
                                         add(b1);
                                          add(b2);
                                          setSize(444,555);
                                   setVisible(true);
                             setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                                b1.addActionListener(this);
                             b2.addActionListener(this);
                                            }
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                     {
                       Object o=e.getSource();

                                if(o==b2)
                            {
                            System.exit(1);

                               }
                          String n1=t1.getText();
                            String n2=t2.getText();
                         int a=Integer.parseInt(n1);
                          int b=Integer.parseInt(n2);
                                  t3.setText(""+(a+b)); 
                         }
                                }
                                      class Gi 
                           {
                        public static void main(String[] args) 
                            {
                        new calc();
                                  }
                                 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said I am new to JAVA and still dont understand this.